# Proof Rényi entropy is non negative

Tags: quantum-information, entropy

The Rényi entropy is defined as:
\begin{equation}
S_\alpha = \dfrac{1}{1-\alpha}\log(\text{Tr}(\rho^\alpha))
\end{equation}
for $\alpha \geq 0$. This can be rewrited in terms of $\rho$ eigenvalues, $\rho_k$, which verify $0 \leq \rho_k \leq 1$, as:
\begin{equation}
S_\alpha = \dfrac{1}{1-\alpha}\log(\sum_k \rho_k^\alpha)
\end{equation}
How can one proof rigurously that $S_\alpha \geq 0$? I am having trouble with this proof eventhough it seems pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

Consider 3 cases : ($\alpha > 1$, $\alpha < 1$, $\alpha = 1$)

- $\alpha > 1$
  $$
  \sum p_k^{\alpha} \leq \sum p_k = 1 \Rightarrow \log (\text{Tr}(\rho^\alpha)) \leq 0\Rightarrow S_\alpha \geq 0
  $$
- $\alpha < 1$
  $$
  \sum p_k^{\alpha} \geq \sum p_k = 1 \Rightarrow \log (\text{Tr}(\rho^\alpha)) \geq 0\Rightarrow S_\alpha \geq 0
  $$
- $\alpha = 1$
  $$
  S_\alpha =\frac{1}{1 - \alpha}  \log (\text{Tr}(\rho e^{(\alpha - 1)\log \rho})) = - \text{Tr}(\rho \log \rho) = - \sum p_k \log p_k \geq 0
  $$
  And in the last sum we used, that $x \log x \leq 0$ for $x \in [0, 1]$

Comment: Completely true! Thank you so much. In the second case, $\alpha < 1$, the last step should be $S_\alpha \geq 0$ right? It is true that $\log\left(\text{Tr}(\rho^\alpha)\right) \geq 0$, and now $S_\alpha$ is just the product of this quantity by $1/(1-\alpha)$, but since $\alpha < 1$ in this case the inequality still holds and then we have $S_\alpha \geq 0$

Comment: @NambuGotto, yes, definitely, there is a multiplication with by a positive number

Comment: Perfect! Thank you again for your answer. I'm getting into density operator and this kind of stuff and proving every expression I find really helps out.

Comment: @NambuGotto it is a good way to study the subject to workout some exercises, really helps understanding